# How can I refresh a TDBGrid in Delphi to show new records?

Tags: delphi

I'm making a simple database management program. It displays data from the SQL database, you can add new records to the database and modify them, all these in different forms (no, I didn't want to edit in the `TDBGrid`).

I have a Form with a `TDBGrid` and a button to refresh the `TDBGrid`, and a `TDataModule` with `TADOConnection`, `TADOQuery` and `TADODataSource`.

My problem is that the `TDBGrid` refresh only has an effect to updated records, it won't show new records that have been added. The inserting works perfectly, because when I check it in SSMS, the new records are there.

So basically, new records are only shown in the `TDBGrid` when I restart my program.

Here's how I tried the refresh:

```pascal
procedure TFormMain.ButtonRefreshClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.Datasource.DataSet.Refresh;
end;
```

So, how can I completely refresh my `TDBGrid` to show every change?

Comment: You can close and reopen the dataset.

Comment: That was the problem, it works now! Thank you! If you add that as an answer, I can accept that as the solution.

Comment: check to make sure you are using the correct values for TADOConnection.IsolationLevel (The possible values are listed here:  http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TIsolationLevel.html)  You should be able to a refresh if properly set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just close and reopen the dataset:

```
DBGrid1.Datasource.DataSet.Close;
DBGrid1.Datasource.DataSet.Open;
```

Comment: A more efficient method is to add the new tuple to the query (this works with TClientDataSet - I don't know about TADOQuery): imagine that there are 10,000 (or more) tuples in the table - all will be retrieved from the table when the dataset is opened. Adding the new tuple saves this network traffic.

Comment: This depends on whether it’s know what is added/edited/removed. To be sure to refresh the data based on the query and what actually in the db, this is the best option imo.

Comment: I neglected to add that first I delete the tuple from the query's dataset (not from the table) then add the edited tuple, so this covers new and edited. When deleting, I delete from the table and from the dataset - in other words, I try as much as possible not to close the dataset and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.
FDConnection1.FetchOptions.Mode := fmAll;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).